# Broadcast of tensor division by a matrix

Tags: numpy

I was trying to compute the value of a 600x400x100 tensor A divided by 600x400 matrix B along the 3rd axis. You can imagine a video clip of 100 frames, and each 600x400 frames is doing an element-wise division. My code is like:

```py
A/B
```

And the error message says:
*ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (600,400,129) (600,400)*
What's wrong with my codes?

Comment: Please fix your markup using Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an empty axis to `B`, making it `(600, 400, 1)`. [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) will take over the rest.

```
A = np.random.rand(600, 400, 100)
B = np.random.rand(600, 400)

A / B[..., None]
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved this by reshaping B as 600x400x1. A / B[..., None] also works!